# Slide navigation of a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `tableviewcontroller` and when the user clicks on the `barButtonItem` i want this `tableviewontroller` to slide from left to right so it covers only 75% of the view.

And, when the user clicks on the same `barbutton` i want the `tableview` to slide back.

How can i do this programatically.

```
-(IBAction)barButtonClicked {
     self.leftTableview = [[LeftTableViewController alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: What you are describing sounds like side menu. Take a look here: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=side+menu

Comment: I want to add it programatically.

Comment: See a [ready-made solution](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) or a [DIY one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path). I guess this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a container view controller. Add the two view controller you want to show to the container view controller as child view controller.

Wen the user taps the bar button, change the frame of on the the views presented in the container view.

More about custom container view controller can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)barButtonClicked {

    if (self.leftTableview != Nil) {
        self.leftTableview = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width * 0.75, 0, -self.view.frame.size.width * 0.75, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:self.leftTableview];

        //settingDataSource and Delegate - do this after you have tested that everything else is working
        [self.leftTableview setDataSource:self];
        [self.leftTableview setDelegate:self];
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"showMenu" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

   {
        if (self.leftTableview.frame.origin.x < 0) {
            [self.leftTableview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.leftTableview.frame.size.width, self.leftTableview.frame.size.height)];
        } else {
            [self.leftTableview setFrame:CGRectMake(-self.leftTableview.frame.size.width, 0, self.leftTableview.frame.size.width, self.leftTableview.frame.size.height)];
        }
   }

   [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I believe you are confusing UITableView with UITableViewController. In my code, there is made only blank tableView, you will need to set delegate and data source

Comment: Is there a special reason you are not using the modern block syntax for animations?

Comment: No. I am familiar with this syntax and it has always been working. But if modern syntax is better, let me know.

Comment: It is better. Blocks are nice. And Apple recommends using the modern syntax.

Comment: In what it is better? Is it quicker? I understand there are more options, but if I do not need them, I see both possibilities equal.

Comment: So when i click on the barButton again will the tableview close ?

Comment: I am sorry, forgot on that, answer is edited according your comment.

Comment: @Reconquistador Nothing happens. Can you tell me what `showMenu ` is ? and also i want to create the table programatically? Where did you add the datasource and delegates too ?

Comment: showMenu is only name for animation. You call change this string to anything else without any change. 

I have showed example of setting dataSource and delegate, plus added one important missing line, which I have forgot on before.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
#pragma mark - TableView

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
   return 1;
    }   
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return [self.tableData count];
    }
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

   if (!cell){
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

   cell.textLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];

   return cell;
    }
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UINavigationController *nvc;
    UIViewController *rootVC;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: {
        rootVC = [[FirstVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];
     }
       break;
       case 1: {
       rootVC = [[SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
     }
       break;
       case 2: {
       rootVC = [[ThirdVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdVC" bundle:nil];
     }
         break;
         default:
         break;
     }
      nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
      [self openContentNavigationController:nvc];
 }
```

Comment: Don't give several answers to one question. Edit you answer instead. This looks like spamming.